# Convert Flux<ObjectWithLists> to Mono<ObjectWithLists>

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have to following objects

```
class ObjectA {
    List<String> success;
    List<String> failure;
}
```

And

```
class ObjectB {
    List<String> completed;
    List<String> unCompleted;
}
```

These objects map together 1:1, apart from the names.

And I have a service which has the following signature.

```
Flux<ObjectA> serviceMethod() {}
```

And in the controller I'm trying to map this return value to a api response of `Mono<ObjectB>`

Here is my attempt

```
public Mono<ObjectB> controllerMethod() {
        return service.serviceMethod()
            .collectList()
            .flatMap(res -> ObjectB.builder()
                    .completed(res.stream().flatMap(r -> r.getSuccess()).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                    .unCompleted(res.stream().flatMap(r -> r.getFailure()).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                    .build()));
}
```

which isn't compiling due to

> no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that List conforms to Stream<? extends R>

Comment: You should try `map` instead of `flatMap`.

Comment: Also it may be better to use only Reactor methods, not a mix of Reactor + Stream. Just for a better readability as it's too easy to confuse their methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flatMap method requires a Stream parameter.

> res.stream().flatMap(Function<? super T, ? extends Stream<? extends
> R>> mapper)

```
public Mono<ObjectB> controllerMethod() {
    return service.serviceMethod()
            .collectList()
            .map(res -> ObjectB.builder()
                    .completed(res.stream().flatMap(lst -> lst.getSuccess().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                    .unCompleted(res.stream().flatMap(lst -> lst.getFailure().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                    .build());
}
```